Can't install Storybook into my Next.js app
I got TypeError trying to install Storybook in my Next.js app.
I got the Error:
`An error occurred while installing dependencies:
wnt.default is not a function
 Error: TypeError: wnt.default is not a function`

My package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ./src --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ./src --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.+(json|ts|tsx)\"",
    "format:check": "npm run prettier -- --check",
    "format:fix": "npm run prettier -- --write",
    "types:check": "tsc --noEmit --pretty",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "storybook:build": "build-storybook",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "cypress:headless": "cypress run",
    "e2e": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cypress",
    "e2e:headless": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cypress:headless",
    "stage:switch": "node scripts/switch-stage.js",
    "stage:save": "node scripts/save-stage.js",
    "stage:clear": "node scripts/clear-stage.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.9",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.2.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.2.1",
    "next": "^12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.34.2",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mswjs/data": "^0.10.2",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/node": "18.7.14",
    "@types/react": "18.0.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.4",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "inquirer": "^8.2.4",
    "jest": "^29.0.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.0.2",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "msw": "^0.47.4",
    "msw-devtools": "^1.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "ts-eager": "^2.0.2",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": "public"
  }
}

I tried to install the latest Storybook into existing project:
npx storybook@latest init
Result: Error: TypeError: wnt.default is not a function`
Expected result: Storybook succesfully installed.

I fixed it by bumping up the version of storybook-addon.
// package.json:
...
"@chakra-ui/storybook-addon": "^5.1.0",
...

